# Workflow for Dapp Development

Tags: dapp-development, mix, truffle, ether-camp, meteor

There is so much information out there that turns around this point that I decided to make a post, can someone please help out?

Does that sound correct as a work-flow for medium/large size projects ?:

- Use Mix IDE (can I use it with geth?) or ethercamp Ethereum Studios to write and test the contracts.
- Use Meteor and Webstorm(or some other javascript IDE) to Build the platform, eventually using place-holder javascript variables until the contracts are ready.
- Move the contracts over to the meteor file structure and add the tested functions to the relevant javascript files.
- Does truffle fit in somewhere in that picture or will it just create noise since there will already be the Meteor framework?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Mix IDE is officially supported by Ethereum, and can be used with
  geth. But you could use either of them based on your preference.
- You could also take a look at some other [Javascript IDEs](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/text-editors-meteor-development/),
  specially atom.
- As far as I know, Meteor+web3js is sufficient, and trying to use
  Truffle or Embark will only make it more confusing.